# Does regex match length need to be checked to determine if at least one match?

Tags: javascript, regex, match

If I am only concerned whether there was at least one match, is there any reason to check the length of the returned array, or is just checking whether the returned value is not null sufficient?

javascript regular expressions match

```
var str = "The rain in SPAIN stays mainly in the plain";
var n = str.match(/ain/g);
if(n && n.length > 0) {alert('at least one match');
// Or
if(n) {alert('at least one match');
```

Comment: A little experimentation will tell you a lot.

Comment: @Jeffman.  On my browser, I don't need to check the length, but that doesn't mean there are not many browsers which act differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It returns null if no match are found (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)
so ,

```
if(n) {alert('at least one match');
```

is sufficient.

You can actually test this,

```
var str = "The rain in SPAIN stays mainly in the plain";
var n = str.match(/ainyyyy/g);
if(n) {console.log('at least one match')}else{console.log('not found');};
```

in this example *not found* will be printed.

Comment: Thanks melc,  Works for me.  Is it safe to assume that documentation described by mozilla.org pertains to all relatively recent browsers?

Comment: @user1032531 yes it is a reference to the ECMAScript standard https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question it's mentioned in [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)

> With g flag,if there were no matches, the method returns null

So,no need to check length

---

You can instead use [search](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search) which accepts regex as a parameter and returns the position

```
if(str.search(/ain/)==-1);//not found
else ;//found
```

You can also use [test](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)

```
if(regexp.test(input))
```

Comment: Thanks, I will look into `search()` and `test()`, but it doesn't really answer the question.